# Showing that a subrepresentation is isomorphic to the trivial representation

Tags: representation-theory

I'm considering $V$ to be the regular representation of a group $G$ and $W$ to be the 1-dimensional subspace of $V$ generated by the element $x=\sum_{s\in G} e_s$. I'm trying to show that $W$ is a subrepresentation of $V$ and that $W$ is isomorphic to the trivial representation of $G$. The first part is easy, but I'd appreciate a solution for the second part.

Comment: What is $e_s$ ?

Comment: $e_s$ are the basis vectors of $V$ indexed by the elements $s$ of $G$.

Comment: Notice that $g.x=x$ for all $g\in G$. Thus, $g$ correspond to $I_n$. As $W$ is one dimensional, every $g$ goes to $1$.

Comment: The reason that $gx=x$ is that $g$ permutes all base vector hence their sum is constant.

Comment: Can you say what the explicit isomorphism will be? I don't seem to understand from the comment.

Comment: A trvial representation of $G$ is a  vector space $U$ (with being $G$ module) such that $gu=u$ for all $u\in U$ right ?